# Unity is broken after upgrading to 12.10 (Optimus laptop)

Tags: unity, upgrade, xorg, 12.10, nvidia-optimus

I upgraded to GNU/Linux Ubuntu 12.10 but have been unable to use Unity properly afterwards. Indeed, I encountered the exact same problem as a lot of people: the Unity side and top bars are not displaying, although in my case, Unity seems completely broken, as I can't even right-click.
However, in my case, it's worth noticing that I have **an Optimus laptop with a Nvidia graphics card** (GeForce GT 540M). Bumblebee and its 'optirun' command is working just fine, as usual, after the upgrade.

I tried several things, as resetting Compiz and Unity (with the command 'setside unity') -- which works but I have to do it everytime I boot and it resets all my settings -- updating/reinstalling/reconfiguring my Nvidia drivers as well as bumblebee, trying with Nouveau drivers instead of nvidia-current, check if linux-headers-generic were installed (they were). However, I couldn't reset xorg.conf files as they're just not there. **There is neither xorg.conf file, nor its backup** in /etc/X11. I think this is where the problem comes from, although I'm far from an expert. Maybe retrieving a xorg.conf file will fix this mess, but I have no idea how to do that.

I'm just tired and don't know what to do. So, here I am, begging for your help.

Answer (score 1):

On my Dell XPS 15z (Optimus graphics), I had the same problem. I managed to get the computer working again by completely removing all the nvidia drivers. (For me, it was not enough to simply remove xorg.conf; instead, the nvidia drivers had to be completely uninstalled.)

This is what I did: note that you can open a terminal by pressing ctrl+alt+T

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

then rebooted.

Of course, this is not ideal, because the nvidia graphics is completely useless, but it will give a working desktop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
However, like mentioned previously, I don't have any xorg.conf file so the second command failed. The rest succeeded but it had no effect: still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the Nvidia Geforce GTX 560M which also uses the proprietary drivers. 
Basically what I did was,

1. open terminal or a shell
2. run command: `sudo apt-get install linux-source`
3. run command: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic`
4. run command: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates`

Then reboot the computer. That worked for me anyway.

Comment: Thanks!However, I can't do that as `nvidia-current-updates` is not compatible with bumblebee (community-made, open-source Nvidia Optimus technology), which is required if I want to use my graphics card (I play games sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

If you use bumbleblee simply reinstall it.
[bumbleblee on ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)

I had exactly the same problem and it solved the fact that unity was broken.

Comment: Thansks for the reply!
But this had no effect. :/

Answer (score 0):

i would try to  reinstall desktop: **sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop**   then run: **sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity** .
Usefull info that might help command to restart Unity: **setsid unity** ,to restart Compiz: **setsid compiz --replace** ,restart X Display: Manager: 
**sudo -s** , then run:
**setsid service lightdm restart**

Comment: I reinstalled/erased the configuration files of both Compiz and Unity, but the result is the same.